# I need to restrict the employee's role access to an entire model in my rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know where to implement this, yet my employee user should not have any access to my costs Model at all. I have already added a conditional statement in my costs/index.html.erb file which restricts the employee's access to the view of the costs. Yet the employee can still access the EDIT, the DESTROY.
What can I do in order to restrict complete access to my employee for an entire model?
Does this need to be established in the routes.rb file?
I also have cancan and Devise installed if that provides any clarification.
If someone can please provide me with a detailed how to since I am trying various approaches even by following the rubyonrails guides and I am still having issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this kind of problem is to write a method in your application controller to be used as a `before_action` that restricts access to controller methods to permitted users only.

It does not restrict access at the Model level, so you can be the judge as to whether or not this approach suits you needs.

Here's an example to give you the idea:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def require_access_to_costs
    unless current_user.is_admin?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You aren't allowed to view this page"
    end
  end
end

class CostsController < ApplicationController
  # This before action will prevent unauthorized access
  before_action :require_access_to_costs

  def show
    # ...
  end
  def edit
    # ...
  end
  def create
    # ...
  end
end
```

You may have to do something more a bit more sophisticated, but this should get you started.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Notice that you can limit the `before_action` to `:only` particular methods in the controller if you like, or `:except` particular methods. Very handy!

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I am being thrown an error that states: "NoMethodError in CostsController#index" and "undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x007ff52d8065e0>" Thank you for bearing with my ignorance I am still new to Rails

Comment: any insight would be appreciated

Comment: That was just an *example* to give you the general idea. You will need to do whatever check is appropriate in your app to determine whether the user should or should not have access.

Comment: Great to hear! Do me a favour and click the tick next to my my answer to accept it.